# ionic throws an error module misspelled or forgot to load even after giving it correctly ?

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework

```
angular.module('todo', ['ionic', 'ngCordova', 'ngMaterial', 'services'])
```

this is how i have included the services module.
this is my services.js file

```
angular.module('services', [])
.service('UserService', function() {
// For the purpose of this example I will store user data on ionic local storage but you should save it on a database
 var setUser = function(user_data) {
  window.localStorage.starter_facebook_user = JSON.stringify(user_data);
 };

 var getUser = function(){
  return JSON.parse(window.localStorage.starter_facebook_user || '{}');
 };

 return {
 getUser: getUser,
 setUser: setUser
 };
 });
```

But i get the error of module misspelled or forgot to load.

Comment: try add todo.services in both app.js and services.js

Comment: Thanks i will try it.